# Why stack flow before execute main()

Tags: c++, stack, project, program-entry-point

I wrote code to implement graph's ADT with adjacent matrix. Then I want to build a project and desperate code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<algorithm>

#define INF 0x3f3f3f3f
using namespace std;
const int maxn=1e3+10;

class Graph{
private:
    int vertex;
    int side;
    int is_vis[maxn];
    int degree[maxn];
    int Edges[maxn][maxn];
public:
    Graph(){
        vertex=0;
        memset(Edges,0x3f,sizeof Edges);
        memset(is_vis,0,sizeof is_vis);
        memset(degree,0,sizeof degree);
    }

    void Clear(){
        vertex=0;
        memset(Edges,0x3f,sizeof Edges);
        memset(is_vis,0,sizeof is_vis);
        memset(degree,0,sizeof degree);
    }

    void Clear_Vis(){memset(is_vis,0,sizeof is_vis);}

    void PreVisit(int v){cout<<v<<" ";}

    void SetMark(int u,int vis){is_vis[u]=vis;}

    void Set_vertex(int n){vertex=n;}            //顶点数

    int  Get_vertex(){return vertex;}

    int  Get_side()  {return side;}              //边数

    void Add_edge(int u,int v,int val){          //加边
        if(Edges[u][v]==INF){
            side++;
            degree[u]++;degree[v]++;
        }
        Edges[u][v]=Edges[v][u]=val;
    }

    void Cancle_edge(int u,int v){               //删边
         if(Edges[u][v]!=INF){
            side--;
            degree[u]--;degree[v]--;
        }
        Edges[u][v]=Edges[v][u]=INF;
    }

    bool Have_edge(int u,int v){                 //判断边是否存在
        return Edges[u][v]==INF?0:1;
    }

    int Get_degree(int u){                       //返回顶点u的度数
        return degree[u];
    }

    void The_edge_node(int u){                   //与顶点u相邻的点
        int flag=1;
        for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
            if(i!=u&&Edges[u][i]!=INF){
                cout<<i<<" ";flag=0;
            }
        }
        if(flag)cout<<"No node next to "<<u<<".";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    void DFS(int u){                             //深度优先遍历
        if(is_vis[u])return;
        PreVisit(u);
        SetMark(u,1);
        for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
            if(i==u||Edges[u][i]==INF||is_vis[i])continue;
            DFS(i);
        }
    }

    void BFS(int u){                             //宽度优先遍历
        memset(is_vis,0,sizeof is_vis);
        queue<int>Q;
        Q.push(u);
        is_vis[u]=1;
        while(!Q.empty()){
            int out=Q.front();Q.pop();
            cout<<out<<" ";
            for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
                if(i==out||Edges[out][i]==INF||is_vis[i])continue;
                is_vis[i]=1;
                Q.push(i);
            }
        }
    }

    void prt_Gra(){                             //打印邻接矩阵
        cout<<"  ";
        for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
            cout<<" "<<left<<setw(3)<<i;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++){
            cout<<"  ";
            for(int j=0;j<vertex*4;j++)cout<<"-";cout<<"-"<<endl;
            cout<<left<<setw(2)<<i;
            for(int j=0;j<vertex;j++){
                cout<<"|";
                if(i==j)cout<<left<<setw(3)<<0;
                else if(Edges[i][j]==INF)cout<<left<<setw(3)<<'-';
                else cout<<left<<setw(3)<<Edges[i][j];
            }
            cout<<"|"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"  ";
        for(int j=0;j<vertex*4;j++)cout<<"-";cout<<"-"<<endl;
    }
}My_graph;

void Get_menus(){
    cout<<"1.新建一个图。"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.增加一条边。"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.删除一条边。"<<endl;
    cout<<"4.判断边是否存在。"<<endl;
    cout<<"5.查询顶点的度数。"<<endl;
    cout<<"6.输出图的邻接矩阵。"<<endl;
    cout<<"7.查询与顶点相邻的点。"<<endl;
    cout<<"8.对图进行深度优先遍历。"<<endl;
    cout<<"9.对图进行宽度优先遍历。"<<endl;
}

int main(){
    My_graph.Clear();
    int cmd,n,m,u,from,to,dist;

    Get_menus();
    while(1){
        cout<<"请输入对应操作的序号：";cin>>cmd;cout<<endl;
        if(cmd==1){
            My_graph.Clear();
            cout<<"请输入图的顶点数：";cin>>n;
            My_graph.Set_vertex(n);cout<<endl;
            cout<<"请输入图的边数：";cin>>m;cout<<endl;
            cout<<"请依次输入各边的端点与长度："<<endl;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                cin>>from>>to>>dist;
                My_graph.Add_edge(from,to,dist);
            }
            cout<<"图的初始化完成！"<<endl;
        }
        if(cmd==2){
            cout<<"请输入新增边的端点与长度："<<endl;
            cin>>from>>to>>dist;
            My_graph.Add_edge(from,to,dist);
            cout<<"加边完成！"<<endl;
        }
        if(cmd==3){
            cout<<"请输入边的两个端点：";
            cin>>from>>to;
            My_graph.Cancle_edge(from,to);
            cout<<"删边完成！"<<endl;
        }
        if(cmd==4){
            cout<<"请输入边的两个端点：";
            cin>>from>>to;
            if(My_graph.Have_edge(from,to))cout<<"该边存在！"<<endl;
            else cout<<"该边不存在！"<<endl;
        }
        if(cmd==5){
            cout<<"请输入需要查询度数的顶点：";
            cin>>u;cout<<endl;
            cout<<"顶点"<<u<<"的度数为："<<My_graph.Get_degree(u)<<endl;
        }
        if(cmd==6){
            cout<<"图的邻接矩阵为："<<endl;
            My_graph.prt_Gra();
        }
        if(cmd==7){
            cout<<"请输入需要查询相邻点的顶点：";
            cin>>u;cout<<endl;
            cout<<"与顶点"<<u<<"相邻的点有："<<endl;
            My_graph.The_edge_node(u);
        }
        if(cmd==8){
            My_graph.Clear_Vis();
            cout<<"请输入起点：";
            cin>>u;cout<<endl;
            cout<<"深度优先遍历的结果为："<<endl;
            My_graph.DFS(u);cout<<endl;
        }
        if(cmd==9){
            cout<<"请输入起点：";
            cin>>u;cout<<endl;
            cout<<"宽度优先遍历的结果为："<<endl;
            My_graph.BFS(u);cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
6 9
0 1 10
0 3 20
0 5 3
1 2 3
1 3 5
3 4 11
2 4 15
3 5 10
4 5 3
*/
```

But when I run the code, CodeBlocks says ''multiple definition of `My_graph'`.

[image]

Then I choose to define Graph's object in `main()` instead of in `Graph.h`. But this time the exe will exit before execute `main()`.

> Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

This is `main()`code

[image]

I want to figure out what happened in constructor.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] and provide error messages as text exactly as you get it from compiler or IDE, not images or links to images.

Comment: @Slava Sorry my level is too low to post pictures....T_T

Comment: @YixuanTang He explicitly said not to post images.

Comment: Is this a stack overflow or underflow?

Comment: A wild guess: `Graph` is too big to be a local variable.

Comment: @YixuanTang sorry I did not ask you to post pictures, I asked quite opposite. Do you have enough permissions to post text?

Comment: You are allocating ont eh stack a huge amount of objects (`const int maxn=1e3+10;`), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @YixuanTang 1e3+10 in base 16 is 123664 in base 10. that is too large of an amount of data to allocate on the stack.

Comment: What is "desparate code"?

Comment: Also, be aware that constructors of global objects will be run before the `main` function is executed.  Check your constructor and make sure it is bullet proof.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not allocating your data on the stack, you won't be able to execute your code. This is the amount of data you want to allocate:

```
const int maxn=1e3+10;
int is_vis[maxn];
int degree[maxn];
int Edges[maxn][maxn];
```

I don't think your computer has enough space.

Use vectors, and resize the edges matrix ont he fly (do you need a matrix anyway? Probably not)

```
std::vector<int> is_vis;
std::vector<int> degree;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Edges; // Change this to something sensible, perhaps a list of connections?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only for one error message "multiple definition...". For the other error see @MatthieuBrucher answer.

---

```
class Graph{
....
} My_graph;
```

This declares an instance global object of type `Graph` called `My_graph`.

Once you have this instance you **can not** declare it again:

```
Graph My_graph; //ERROR
```

This re-declaration may come not only in some function ('main' is a function) , but also from including the same .h header several times without include-guards.